# load some content from txt and add to html markup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

Have some markup

```
<div class="container">
    <aside class="left">
        <div class="item"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    </aside>
    <aside class="right">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </aside>
</div>
<button>load more</button>
```

css

```
aside {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

I need to load some html content from .txt file when clicking `button` and add that markup inside both `aside`. In .txt file markup like this

```
<div class="item"><p>lorem ipsum1</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>lorem ipsum2</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>lorem ipsum3</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>lorem ipsum4</p></div>
```

I want "drag" and paste first div with class `.item` to `aside.left`, second div with class `.item` in `aside.right`, third div with class `.item` in `aside.left` and so on...

Is there any solution? I don't know how paste `.item` divs in both columns..

Thanks for any help

Here is [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c3r7xqxu/)

upd: I'm only use css+html+some jquery, I dont know any things on php or server technology.. but programmer who work with my markup says that I need to demonstrate how content will be added on click.. So I dont know is this my work, or this is programmer need to do.. I need your answer about this..
If that helps, here is [LINK](http://homeradar.hol.es/) you can see site. In bottom you can see arrow, onclick on that there need add content in columns..

P.S. Programmer works with Yii framework.

Comment: You havent actually tried to do it

Comment: So, please add which language are you working with.c# or php?and what is your technology?mvc or something else?

Comment: I updated main question, see please.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already seem to know about `AJAX` (you added the tag), I think you have your answer there.

You can just use AJAX to get any chunk of data from the server and add it to the page.

Since you are working together with a server-side programmer, I think each of you could build their own part independantly.

All you need is an API that you can use, to which you can specify the offset of items to load, so you could call `/getitems?offset=12&count=4` to get the next 4 items from item 12.

You can then just make a simple page that returns dummy data. `getitems.php` can just return the same constant items every time, and all you need to do is add those items at the bottom of your list.

At the same time, the PHP programmer can actually implement that page so it returns the same data. He can make it in such a way that it also works for non-AJAX request, so he can easily test it without needing your front-end code.